# How to address the "alias" in SQL statement

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause, alias

I am trying to filter a join result but having issues with an alias `cPlace`.

Here are my joins that work but fails on the `WHERE` clause. I am basically showing the ISO country code and where the country is is 107 (USA) show the State abbreviation.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN co.CIDNo = 107 THEN al.State ELSE co.ISO 
    END AS cPlace, 
    al.ALIDNo 
FROM 
    dbo.AssignedList AS al
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Country co ON al.CIDNo = co.CIDNo
-->>> Fails after this point
WHERE 
    al.cPlace IN ('ALB', 'ATG', 'BEN', 'BFA', 'BHS', 'BLM', 'COM', 'Con', 'CT', 'ERI', 'ETH', 'GA', 'GLP', 'GUY', 'HI', 'KAZ', 'LBY', 'MA', 'MCO', 'MLT', 'MN', 'NPL', 'PRI', 'ROM', 'SDN', 'SGP', 'SLE', 'SLV', 'TGO', 'TN', 'UZB', 'WSM')
```

Results before the `WHERE` clause:

```
cPlace ALIDNo
--------------
DZA     1
AGO     2
BEN     3
CT      4
BFA     5
BDI     6
NY      7
```

Thank you all in advance on for your assistance.

Comment: You need to nest your query, either using a *Common Table Expression* (`WITH...`)  or a *Derived Table* (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...)`)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to a column alias in an `on` clause or `where` clause.

One option is to just repeat the logic:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN co.CIDNo = 107 THEN al.State ELSE co.ISO END) AS cPlace, 
       al.ALIDNo 
FROM dbo.AssignedList al INNER JOIN
     dbo.Country co
     ON al.CIDNo = co.CIDNo
WHERE (CASE WHEN co.CIDNo = 107 THEN al.State ELSE co.ISO END) IN (. . .);
```

Another option is to use a subquery/CTE/`apply` to define the alias:

```
SELECT v.cPlace, al.ALIDNo 
FROM dbo.AssignedList al INNER JOIN
     dbo.Country co
     ON al.CIDNo = co.CIDNo CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ( CASE WHEN co.CIDNo = 107 THEN al.State ELSE co.ISO END )
     ) v(cPlace)
WHERE cPlace IN (. . .);
```